# random image slideshow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

i have image slideshow with these codes:-

Jquery:-

```
$(function() {
var current = 0,

    $imgs = jQuery('#header .abc71');
    imgAmount = $imgs.length;

$($imgs.css('position', 'absolute').hide().get(0)).show();


window.setInterval(swapImages, 4000);

function swapImages() {
    var $currentImg = $($imgs[current]);
    if(current == imgAmount-1) current = -1;
    var $nextImg = $($imgs[++current]),
        speed = 1500;
    // animation speed should be the same for both images so we have a smooth change
    $currentImg.fadeOut(speed);
    $nextImg.fadeIn(speed);
    }
});
```

html:-

```
<div id="header">
   <img class="abc71" src="img1.png"/>
   <img class="abc71" src="img2.png" />
   <img class="abc71" src="img3.png"/>
 </div>
```

these scripts working well. but i want to display images in random order. how i modify my scripts for that. or should i use any other scripts? plz help me... Thankz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. I updated some of your code to make it cleaner. Use the fun selectors like :hidden and :visible. They're really great.

Here's the fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQ2Zu/1/)

```
$(function () {
var current = 0,

$imgs = jQuery('#header .abc71');
imgAmount = $imgs.length;

$($imgs.css('position', 'absolute').hide().get(0)).show();


window.setInterval(swapImages, 1000);

function swapImages() {

    var $currentImg = $('.abc71:visible');

    var $nextImg = $('.abc71:hidden').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.abc71:hidden').length));
        speed = 500;
    // animation speed should be the same for both images so we have a smooth change
    $currentImg.fadeOut(speed);
    $nextImg.fadeIn(speed);
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) to generate random index for image array if random number is greater then length then set it to image array `length-1`.

```
$(function() {
    var current = 0,      
    $imgs = jQuery('#header .abc71');
    imgAmount = $imgs.length;    
    $($imgs.css('position', 'absolute').hide().get(0)).show();
    window.setInterval(swapImages, 4000);

    function swapImages() {
        current = Math.floor((Math.random()*imgAmount)+1);
    if(current > imgAmount-1) current = imgAmount -2;
    var $currentImg = $($imgs[current]);       
    var $nextImg = $($imgs[current+1]),
        speed = 1500;
    // animation speed should be the same for both images so we have a smooth change
    $currentImg.fadeOut(speed);
    $nextImg.fadeIn(speed);

    }
});
```

Comment: hi adil, thankz  for ur answer, but this not working for me, i added ur script to my page, but slideshow not working, only first image loaded :(

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? on jsfiddle.net